# What are the names used in computer science for some of the following tree data types?

Tags: haskell, types, tree

Sometimes I get myself using different types of trees in Haskell and I don't know what they are called or where to get more information on algorithms using them or class instances for them, or even some pre-existing code or library on hackage.

Examples:

Binary trees where the labels are on the leaves or the branches:

```
data BinTree1 a = Leaf | 
                  Branch {label :: a, leftChild :: BinTree1 a, rightChild :: BinTree1 a}

data BinTree2 a = Leaf {label :: a} | 
                  Branch {leftChild :: BinTree2 a, rightChild :: BinTree2 a}
```

Similarly trees with the labels for each children node or a general label for all their children:

```
data Tree1 a = Branch {label :: a, children :: [Tree1 a]}

data Tree2 a = Branch {labelledChildren :: [(a, Tree2 a)]}
```

Sometimes I start using `Tree2` and somehow on the course of developing it gets refactored into `Tree1`, which seems simpler to deal with, but I never gave a lot of thought about it. Is there some kind of duality here?

Also, if you can post some other different kinds of trees that you think are useful, please do.

In summary: everything you can tell me about those trees will be useful! :)

Thanks.

EDIT:

Clarification: this is not homework. It's just that I usually end up using those data types and creating instances (Functor, Monad, etc...) and maybe if I new their names I would find libraries with stuff implemented and more theoretical information on them.

Usually when a library on Hackage have Tree in the name, it implements BinTree2 or some version of a non-binary tree with labels only on the leaves, so it seems to me that maybe Tree2 and BinTree2 have some other name or identifier.

Also I feel that there may be some kind of duality or isomorphism, or a way of turning code that uses Tree1  into code that uses Tree2 with some transformation. Is there? May be it's just an impression.

Comment: It's just a tree. What do you want to know, really? "Everything" is not concrete enough for an SO question.

Comment: Well, clearly those two trees are different. Are there some kind of mathematical relation between them? Some kind of duality?

Comment: Nope. It's just someone with no formal education on computer science (I'm a physicist) which eventually bumps into things he doesn't understand.

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini: The differences are mostly just implementation details, there's no fundamental difference between these types (apart from general tree vs. binary tree)

Comment: @NiklasB. So, they are isomorphic is some sense? Can I transform a code that uses BinTree1 in a code that uses BinTree2?

Comment: BinTree2 ist just a special case where the inner nodes have no labels.

Comment: No computer scientist I have ever met or heard of would call those data structures anything other than "binary trees."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names I've heard:

- `BinTree1` is a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)
- `BinTree2` don't know a name but you can use such a tree to represent a prefix-free code like huffman coding for example
- `Tree1` is a [Rose tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_Tree)
- `Tree2` is isomoprhic to `[Tree1]` (a forest of `Tree1`) or another way to view it is a `Tree1` without a label for the root.

Comment: BinTree1 can be qualified as a "node labelled binary tree" whereas BinTree2 is a "leaf labelled binary Tree". I don't know of any useful naming for Tree2.

Answer (score 5):

A binary tree that only has labels in the leaves (`BinTree2`) is usually used for hash maps, because the tree structure itself doesn't offer any information other than the binary position of the leaves.

So, if you have 4 values with the following hash codes:

```
...000001 A
...000010 B
...000011 C
...000010 D
```

... you might store them in a binary tree (an implicit patricia trie) like so:

```
     +          <- Bit #1 (least significant bit) of hash code
    / \            0 = left, 1 = right
   /   \
[B, D]  +       <- Bit #2
       / \
      /   \
     [A]  [C]
```

We see that since the hash codes of `B` and `D` "start" with `0`, they are stored in the left root child. They have exactly the same hash codes, so no more forks are necessary. The hash codes of `A` and `C` both "start" with 1, so another fork is necessary. `A` has bit 2 as `0`, so it goes to the left, and C with `1` goes to the right.

This hash table implementation is kind of bad, because hashes might have to be recomputed when certain elements are inserted, but no matter.

---

`BinTree1` is just an ordinary binary tree, and is used for fast order-based sets. Nothing more to say about it, really.

---

The only difference between `Tree1` and `Tree2` is that `Tree2` can't have root node labels. This means that if used as a prefix tree, it cannot contain the empty string. It has very limited use, and I haven't seen anything like it in practice. `Tree1`, however, obviously has an use as a non-binary prefix tree, as I said.

Comment: Actually a hash table is implemented using an array

Comment: @NiklasB., that's another way of doing it, but not necessarily the only way. If your data structure has to be immutable, a tree is much more convenient.

Comment: I think you are confusing a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with a [hash tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree). A hash table or hash map, by definition, is a table, not a tree. Of course that's not really important, just me nitpicking a bit about other people's posts :)

Comment: I guess "hash map" would be the more general term that is appropriate here, then, as "associative array" would be too general.

Comment: I have to retract my earlier comment, hash map is a fine term. Wikipedia calls them [Hash array mapped types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie), by the way, just FYI or that of others.